# "Enemies of something"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hopefully you are fine!

When we say about someone is an "enemy of something", it means that he or she is an enemy of that something and is against it.

But, here are two passages where it is difficult to perceive this meaning.

The first is:

> He was, however, a vigorous defender of a conception of natural
>   science that served in his mind as the antidote to vain and fruitless
>   philosophical investigation. In clarifying this new distinction
>   between science and philosophy, and especially in fighting vigorously
>   for it in public campaigns directed against **the perceived enemies of
>   fanaticism and superstition**, Voltaire pointed modern philosophy down
>   several paths that it subsequently followed.

The second is:

> This apparent victory in the Newton Wars of the 1730s and 1740s
>   allowed Voltaire's new philosophical identity to solidify. Especially
>   crucial was the way that it allowed Voltaire's outlaw status, which he
>   had never fully repudiated, to be rehabilitated in the public mind as
>   a necessary and heroic defense of philosophical truth against **the
>   enemies of error and prejudice**. From this perspective, Voltaire's
>   critical stance could be reintegrated into traditional Old Regime
>   society as a new kind of legitimate intellectual martyrdom.

Both passages are from [an article on Voltaire](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/voltaire/).

Apparently, it seems that, in the first passage, **the perceived enemies of
 fanaticism and superstition** are those traditionalists who Voltaire fought against. So, it is something like **the perceived warriors of fanaticism and superstition who were enemies of Enlightenment**. In other words, "fanaticism" and "superstition" are in fact properties of the "enemies".

The same is the case in the second passage.

I want your view on it. As I was not able to find any such meaning in the online dictionaries, I want confirmation or correction of my perception of the meaning of "enemies" in the aforementioned two passages.

Comment: Hello, Musshraf, and welcome to EL&U. However, as @choster has said,  our Q&A format is designed to answer specific, narrowly-focused questions, and is not well-suited to interpreting articles or passages. Probably here, 'enemies' is a usage of personification, though this could also be an example of metonymy (using 'fanaticism is the enemy of ...' for 'fanatics are the enemy of ...').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your help.

Regarding the scope of question, I was, in fact, thinking that I have narrowed my question to the meaning of "of" in a specific context. I copied many lines from the article just to put it in the context. But, definitely, it may have not got such specificity which is required for this forum. I am hopeful to learn it with the passage of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question raises the very important issue of ambiguous language used within such a precise and exacting field of study as Philosophy should be. It is the author's use of the preposition [**of**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of) which has caused the problem in proper comprehension of the article.

Of can refer to different types of associations between different entities. In this case the association is between *enemies* and certain traits like *fanaticism, superstition, error, and prejudice*. So it could be read in one of two different ways:

- people [enemies] who are *against* those particular traits
- negative traits which happen to be viewed as *enemies*

To clarify the ambiguity, the author could have improved his sentence structure with several methods. Using the first example for demonstration, I would consider striking out **of**, and using a *colon* there instead:

> In clarifying this new distinction between science and philosophy, and especially in fighting vigorously for it in public campaigns directed against the perceived **enemies**: o̶f̶  **fanaticism and superstition**, Voltaire pointed modern philosophy down several paths that it subsequently followed.

Or, strike out **of** and use a *comma* instead:

> In clarifying this new distinction between science and philosophy, and especially in fighting vigorously for it in public campaigns directed against the perceived **enemies**, o̶f̶  **fanaticism and superstition**, Voltaire pointed modern philosophy down several paths that it subsequently followed.

Or, strike out **of** and use *parentheses* to set off the undesirable traits to be viewed as *enemies*:

> In clarifying this new distinction between science and philosophy, and especially in fighting vigorously for it in public campaigns directed against the perceived **enemies** o̶f̶  (**fanaticism and superstition**), Voltaire pointed modern philosophy down several paths that it subsequently followed.

It is just unfortunate that the author of such an interesting article on a subject of philosophy made such a poor choice of wording their sentences with respect to the use of the associated words, **enemies** and **of**. The preposition only introduced unnecessary confusion.

Comment: -1 it is a perfectly natural and common use of the preposition *of*; saying otherwise is to mislead the OP

Comment: @user9825893y50932 ~ It's ambiguous, and something to be avoided. I'm sure that's why the OP had a problem with it enough to ask the question. But you're free to downvote anyway.

Comment: Yes, striking out the OF removes the ambiguity. An apposition works better here. The of in X of Y can mean: constituted by and not belonging to. I like your explanation.

Comment: Not a bad answer -  although I'd say that the word "perceived" makes it even more ambiguous  -  did the author really mean to suggest "fanaticism and superstition that Voltaire had perceived" ?

Comment: Other approaches (as you suggested with "negative traits") might be to eliminate 'enemies'/'perceived enemies' or replace it poetically with "the twin evils of fanaticism and superstition" .. if that was what the author meant to say ( it is so ambiguous that I'm not really certain to be honest)

Comment: @Bread Thank you very much. Your explanation really makes sense to me. And, it didn't cross my mind that it can have the sense that "fanaticism is itself an enemy". As, I am a student of Arabic as well and such a use is very much common in it but I didn't find such a use common in English - within the limits of what I have read until now - so I was confused. Thanks once again. This will really open a venue for me in understanding the standard English text in future. I am, being a student, hopeful to get such help in future as well.

Comment: @Bread Just to view the meaning which you suggested in the mirror of the meanings mentioned in oxforddictionaries,com, I would like to ask the following:

Is it right to say that this meaning lies under the following usage (five one) or category:

"Expressing the relationship between a general category or type and the thing being specified which belongs to such a category." ?

As, there are many enemies and "fanaticism" is one of them.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of

Comment: @Mushrraf Baig Shraf ~ Thank you. Obviously the sheer number of meanings that *of* may convey is naturally a source of confusion at times. And I agree that you have made a very astute observation in choosing (5) as the one likely intended by the author (not to mention the brilliance of your question to start with). So, using **of** is correct -- technically. The only problem with it in this case is that in such a complex explanation, there is so much potential for confusion and ambiguity.

Comment: @Mushrraf Baig Shraf ~ When I read it, I had to stop and really think hard about his intended meaning; and most people would prefer the thoughts we read to flow more easily. I really appreciate you bringing the question to our attention, it is a very interesting one. Also very grateful for you pointing out the most logical intended meaning of "of" in the dictionary, as I was indeed curious but not feeling quite up to the task.

Comment: Thank you @Lambie and Tom22, for the encouragement, and also for the fine suggestions and great ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The word *of* signifies many relationships between the two noun phrases that it joins. For instance the [Cambridge Advanced Learners dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/of) explains many of them.

You seem to know this one:

> John is the *enemy of Bill*.

But there is another relevant usage, that is quite common in English and usually not ambiguous when read in context.

Let's use another word than *enemies*, for example: *sports*.

> I am not interested in the *sports of baseball, football, tennis, and golf*.

Here, this is not the "possessive" use of *of*; if that were so, then the italicized noun phrase could be rewritten as

> [incorrect] *baseball, football, tennis, and golf's sports*

or possibly

> [incorrect] *baseball's, football's, tennis's, and golf's sports*.

Rather, the phrase is used to mean

> *the sports (that are) baseball, football, tennis, and golf*.

Another example is

> John enjoys the subjects of engineering, physics, and biochemistry.

This means

> John enjoys the subjects (that are) engineering, physics, and biochemistry.

The same can be said for the usage of the "enemy clauses*; for example:

> the perceived enemies of fanaticism and superstition

means

> the perceived enemies (that are) fanaticism and superstition.

It is *not*

> [incorrect] fanaticism and superstition's perceived enemies.